# How to return data from an anchored reference

Tags: jquery, href

I have a normal HTML page called Search.asp with an anchored reference that simply invokes another file in the site - in this case PolyDraw.asp:

```
<a href="PolyDraw2.asp">Geographical Comp Selection</a>
```

PolyDraw2.asp uses the Google Maps API to gain some information from the visitor.  In this case the final information is a simple text string of comma-separated numbers:  2012,987,3345,17

This string needs to get back to the original page (Search.asp) that hosted the  so that the numbers can be processed.

PolyDraw2.asp has a RETURN button on top of the map that is captured with jQuery and so the questions are: 1) how to return the string of data to Search.asp and 2) how to close the PolyDraw2.asp window

Thanks

Comment: You need to look up ajax

Comment: You can only close a window with javascript if that window was opened with javascript, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to perform that action and store the response in a variable.

In this case, something like this would work:

```
<a id="polydraw" href="PolyDraw2.asp">Geographical Comp Selection</a>
```

Then you'd make a script like this:

```
$("#polydraw").click(function(e) {
   $.ajax({
       url:this.attr("href"),
       type: 'GET', //(POST?)
       success: function(response) {
           $("selector").html(response);
       },
       error: function(request, settings, exception) {
           console.log(request + ", " + settings + ", " + exception);
       },
       complete: function() {
           console.log("Polydraw complete");
       }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Response should contain your response. You can use post to send data to the page if you need to (controller?)

Comment: OK, the Google Map comes up and my jQuery to use the API seems to work.  How do I now get PolyDraw2.asp to put the list of numbers it developed somewhere that the original page can see?  Also, what is ${"selecter") referring to? And how do I direct JavaScript to close the map page?

Comment: `$("selector")` is a way to select an element on the page with Jquery. For example if you have `<span id="results">`, you can select it by `$("#results")`. Look at the `success: function(response)` statement. Inside the function, you have the variable `response`, which contains the result of your PolyDraw2.asp, if you do `$("#results").html(response)`, it will just dump the result into the element with id="results".

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications!  How to I close the window that was created with aJax?   close();  doesn't seem to work.  Also, if/when I get there, what will be in 'response' ?  Will it be the whole response from the page - all the HTML and the DOM and everything?

Comment: Regarding the page — you’ll have to troubleshoot it, the page is not supposed to open at all. Ah, yes, I think I know why, I forgot to put in `e.preventdefault()` in the code. The response should contain the whole HTML of the page. You can construct an action to specifically return a JSON object, for example, but that's delving into MVC territory.

Comment: e.preventdefault();  didn't seem to alter the behavior.  When the visitor clicks on the "Save and Return" button I want the whole second page to disappear (I thought that self.close(); would do that) AND I need for the original page to be able to access a string of results from the maps page.  Earlier in this thread I got some jQuery code that uses ajax to post up the page and that seems to work.  Now, how to I cause the maps page to close and how do I see the results string?

Comment: I made a typo on preventDefault, it's actually camel-case statement. See this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vcxh6r9f/
It opens jsfiddle in a div. The result is not a new window with the page open, it is the actual page, the HTML code stored in a variable. You can display it in a widget, if you want, or just load elements out of it.

You can use `var win = window.open(); win.document.body.innerHTML = response; win.close()`, but ultimately, you don't need any of that anyway, if you want to just use the coordinates.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the previous comment.

Comment: I'm new to jsFiddle so I hope I'm using it in a reasonable way to show the important snippets of code that demonstrate the problem - https://jsfiddle.net/s9gqnr7c -  The issue is that, while the AJAX executed page does happen it's return/exit/close is not seen in the calling page.

Comment: Aight. This is more clear. So the user experience you want to achieve is this:
1) user clicks the link;
2) new window pops up with an interaction;
3) user interacts with the new window;
4) user clicks “return” in the new window;
5) the old window receives results of user’s interaction in the new window;
6) the new window closes.
This is rather different than simply getting the page loaded into a variable. 
I think opening the new page in a div instead of a window would be a much easier way. Let's see if we can do this with a popup window, though.

Comment: Breakthrough!  I finally have the sequence you described previously working.  The return value goes into an empty **<div>** on the first page.  The Ajax code from earlier brings up the second page and 'window.opener.$("#hiddenreturn").html(tstr);' returns the data string and 'close();' terminates the popup.  I consider this problem essentially solved and I'm moving on to my next test.  Thanks so much to @NOMENATOR for all your help.

Answer (score -1):

What I thought was a jQuery/Ajax problem was really a bad misunderstanding of HTML.  This problem is now resolved.

Comment: This should be a comment.